# Forcing Firefox to validate SSL certificates from Sophos

Tags: firefox, ssl, certificate, blocking, sophos

A network I'm often connected to uses a Sophos network block on many sites. I would like to try to get around this. I looked at the solution from [how to make firefox ignore all ssl certification errors](https://superuser.com/questions/1054724/how-to-make-firefox-ignore-all-ssl-certification-errors) and it doesn't work as I'm not able to export my certificate. I can view it, but not export it as a file.

How would I be able to do this?

Edit: I found the download for the certificate, however Firefox will not allow me to import it. It is saying "This is not a certificate authority certificate, so it can’t be imported into the certificate authority list." when I try.

Edit 2 Electric Boogaloo: I'm realizing that the issue is that the certificate has an unknown issuer. Obviously, I know the issuer is Sophos. I don't know what I can do to force this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ask the network administrator to unblock the sites you need access to.

Comment: @AndrewMorton this sadly is not a viable solution

Comment: If you have a network __block__ then trying to trust the certificate will not help, it will still block but maybe with a nicer error message. If this instead is not about blocking but about __SSL interception__ (i.e. firewall is man in the middle to analyze encrypted traffic, but not to block it) then importing the CA certificate used by the firewall needs to be done. To get this CA certificate you need to ask your network administrator, since this is unique for an installation, i.e. there is no single CA valid for all sophos firewalls in the world.

Comment: Sorry, issues specific to corporate IT are off-topic. You'll have to ask your IT department.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thank you, I'll try to figure that out then.

Comment: If you ARE the IT department, it's fine to ask questions here, we just expect lots more info and a clarification that this is a corporate environment and that you are IT. We don't take questions from line staff in business environments because we don't want to encourage what is often called "shadow IT" and, more often than not, there will be policies applied to the systems that are unique to that environment that they and we are not aware of, so a good answer may not actually be a viable answer.