# Undo "Don't trust this website" in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I mistakenly clicked "Don't trust this website" on a website which has a certificate issue. This is a local website, and the admins are too lazy to fix this issue, but I need to access it anyways.

Now I keep getting an "Secure Connection Failed" error in Firefox.

How can I fix this?

Comment: May be helpful http://superuser.com/questions/826232/how-to-bypass-the-secure-connection-failed-warning-in-firefox-33